# How to create a custom URL, with multiple "dots" and no www?

Tags: url, hosting

How are custom URLs created?  For example:

`reddeer.kijiji.com` (real site)

or

`help.idont.know.com`

The latter of the two may not be possible, with so many 'dot's.

Is such a URL possible from a hosted domain (ie, BlueHost), or is it only possible on a private server built specifically for the site?

I usually use Dreamweaver CS5 to create my sites.  Is there a way of using that software to create custom URLs like these?

Comment: You are talking about subdomains. Do google it for details.

Comment: @aliasm2k Perfect, thanks!  I was hoping it'd be that easy.  Please feel free to make it an answer so I can give you credit for your help!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are talking about subdomains. Do Google it for more details.

Comment: i ended up here googling it tho

Answer (score 0):

Custom URLs (properly, "subdomains") like those are created by adding appropriate "A" or "CNAME" records to the server that handles DNS for your site.  Whether or not you can do it for a hosted domain depends mostly on your DNS provider, not your hosting provider, though a hosting provider who uses "virtual hosting" to fit large numbers of websites on a single machine will need to configure things to work with your subdomains.

What you use to create your site has no impact on your ability to use subdomains.

Comment: Thank you, Mark!  Your answer is really great, but I had promised the acceptance to alias just before you posted yours.  Can I give them both a check!?  I'm new to the site so I can't upvote it yet.  I feel bad.  Again, your answer has been really helpful!